# How to minimize modulated signal clipping in an amplifier circuit with improper Q1 biasing?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, amplitude-modulation, biasing

[image: Two methods of signal modulation]

I'm currently working on two amplifier circuits designed to process modulated signals. While the circuit on the right operates as expected, both theoretically and practically, I'm facing an issue with signal clipping in the left circuit, specifically related to the NPN transistor (denoted as Q1).

I have identified that the problem likely lies with the biasing of Q1, but despite my efforts, I've been unable to pinpoint the exact cause or find an effective solution. The symptoms suggest that Q1 is not correctly biased, leading to undesired clipping of the modulated signal.

Could someone provide insights or recommendations on how to adjust or correct the biasing of Q1 to eliminate or reduce the clipping? Any suggestions on alternative approaches to mitigate this issue would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than make us cull through these schematics, though we can do that if we have the time, why don't you instead save us a little time and talk about each and your methods in setting the DC quiescent operating point and your expectations (predictions) about behavior. It helps to know what you imagine and contrast that with what you then see. I might have time were I to see that. Right now, I don't have the time available, lacking that. (But that's just me.)

Comment: I don't want to guess where n003, n005 and n006 are. Please name all the nodes you're plotting.